# Laravel - All route links are prefixed with sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm using a sub-domain in my application as a dashboard for a user account. In the views of the dashboard, I include a master template which contains links in the navigation that lead to the root of the website. When I visited the sub-domain I've noticed all links in the navigation were changed based on the sub-domain name.

In my master template, links are generated using the helper function **route()**. When a generated link is viewed on my sub-domain, the link changes from **domain.com/about** to **sub.domain.com/about** along with all other links.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'dashboard.project.app', 'before' => 'auth'], function() 
{
    Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController');
});

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');

Route::resource('support', 'SupportController');
```

So visiting **dashboard.project.app** would trigger **getIndex()** in the DashboardController while visiting **project.app** would trigger **index()** in the HomeController.

Great, we've got this far. Now I have a simple view I use as a template that will contain URLs to the named resource routes defined outside of the sub-domain.

Again, URLs are made using the helper function **route()**. In a template extended by a view called in DashboardController I would have a link in the navigation like:

`<a href="{{ route('products.index') }}">Products</a>`

which would generate `<a href="http://project.app/products">Products</a>` as desired however changes to `<a href="http://dashboard.project.app/products">Products</a>` when shown in a view under the sub-domain.

So I would like the desired output to always be **project.app/products** and never **dashboard.project.app/products** as visiting that link will result in a 404 as there is no getProducts() method in my DashboardController. It's the wrong links!

Get what I'm saying?

Answer (score 2):

If the named route is not defined as being specific to a domain, then the url generator will use whatever domain you are currently on. If the route should be specific to a domain, specify it:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'project.app'], function() {
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
    Route::resource('support', 'SupportController');
});
```

Now, even from your dashboard, `route('products.index')` should give you `project.app/products`.